# python: Permission denied

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run a python script in ubuntu using the command

```
python3 preprocess.py
```

But I am getting this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: python: Permission denied
```

The script I am trying to run is a wrapper function that runs two additional python scripts, the label_json_to_tif.py and generate_dataset.py.

This is the permissions of the files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooPAD.png)

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Can we see the contents of `preprocess.py`?

Comment: Hello Ali Tou. Here is the contents of preprocess.py.

https://i.imgur.com/GOnakUy.jpg

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, but have you tried running preprocess.py as sudo? e.g.

```
sudo python3 preprocess.py
```

If this works it would probably be because you are trying to start preprocesses and that may be the thing upsetting your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

I tried to run 
`sudo python3 preprocess.py`

but it gave me this error instead

https://i.imgur.com/LStlYBa.jpg

Comment: I believe the problem is in the cmd1 and cmd 2 lines as you are trying to run "python", try editing those lines to replace 'python {}' with 'python3 {}' for both variables.

Comment: @Masterbond7 that does sound probable